# Oxyplot disable zoom

Tags: c#, xaml, oxyplot

I am using Oxyplot in my C# application, an I want to disable the possibility to zoom in the plot by scrolling on the mouse.

I've tried to set the IsZoomEnabled property on all my axis, but it has no impact.

```
axis.IsZoomEnabled = false;
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe there is a unbind method for the mouse wheel?
http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/controllers/index.html?highlight=zoom

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't seems to work. @RolandDeschain

Comment: @random : yes, it does work...:O) try again, show your code.